# Java Bukkit Events registered more than once

Tags: java, events, for-loop, bukkit

Okay, I've come across with this odd bug since I changed my Menu design on Bukkit API.

Before I stress the problem, here is what the program was supposed to do.

1. When the player joins do the following.
2. Add the player to a HashMap with the menus that he will be using.
3. Loop through the Menus related to that player, and call necessary functions.
4. When the player leaves, remove him from the HashMap and destroy the menu instances.

It goes normal up to step 2, however the events on step 3 seem to get registered equal to the amount of keys inside the HashMap. For example, if 3 players are online, the 4th one's events will be registered **x4 times**, which is a serious memory leak.

Now here's my code, it's the whole class.

```
package src.ares.core.menu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerQuitEvent;

import src.ares.core.Main;
import src.ares.core.common.Module;

public class MenuListener extends Module
{
    private static MenuListener instance = new MenuListener();

    public static MenuListener getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    private HashMap<Player, ArrayList<Menu>> activeMenus;

    public MenuListener()
    {
        super("Menu Listener");

        this.activeMenus = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event)
    {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        ArrayList<Menu> defaultMenus = new ArrayList<>();

        defaultMenus.add(MenuFactory.getFactory().createMenu(MenuType.KIT_MENU));
        defaultMenus.add(MenuFactory.getFactory().createMenu(MenuType.WORLD_MENU));
        defaultMenus.add(MenuFactory.getFactory().createMenu(MenuType.STATS_MENU));

        if (!activeMenus.containsKey(player))
            activeMenus.put(player, defaultMenus);
        else return;

        Main.debug("Before For-Loop.");

        for (Player registered : activeMenus.keySet())
        {
            if (registered.equals(player))
            {
                Main.debug("Player Validation Passed -> " + registered.getName());

                ArrayList<Menu> playerMenus = activeMenus.get(registered);

                for (Menu specificMenu : playerMenus)
                {
                    specificMenu.setSpecificTo(registered);
                    specificMenu.addItems();
                    specificMenu.defineItems();
                    specificMenu.registerEvents();
                    Main.debug("Messing with -> " + specificMenu.getName());
                }

                Main.debug("End of Menus.");
            }
        }
    }

    public HashMap<Player, ArrayList<Menu>> getMenus()
    {
        return activeMenus;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerQuit(PlayerQuitEvent event)
    {
        for (Player registered : activeMenus.keySet())
        {
            if (registered.equals(event.getPlayer()))
            {
                for (Menu playerMenu : activeMenus.get(registered))
                {
                    playerMenu.destroy();
                }

                activeMenus.remove(registered);
                Main.debug("Unregistering Menu Listeners.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question here is. **What could be a possible fix to that problem with events?**
Other than that, everything else works perfect.

Heads up, I've been debugging since yesterday, and no progress.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about your for loops, so I replaced most of the objects with Strings, and called onPlayerJoin() four times to test it out.

```
Player Validation Passed -> aaaaa
Messing with -> MenuType.KIT_MENU
Messing with -> MenuType.WORLD_MENU
Messing with -> MenuType.STATS_MENU
End of Menus.
Player Validation Passed -> bbbbb
Messing with -> MenuType.KIT_MENU
Messing with -> MenuType.WORLD_MENU
Messing with -> MenuType.STATS_MENU
End of Menus.
Player Validation Passed -> ccccc
Messing with -> MenuType.KIT_MENU
Messing with -> MenuType.WORLD_MENU
Messing with -> MenuType.STATS_MENU
End of Menus.
Player Validation Passed -> ddddd
Messing with -> MenuType.KIT_MENU
Messing with -> MenuType.WORLD_MENU
Messing with -> MenuType.STATS_MENU
End of Menus.
```

Everything was only called once and I saw no looping based off the number of players as described in OP. It seems to me like with there is nothing wrong with the way you are looping, but rather the implementation of Bukkit.

One thing that stuck out to me was in onPlayerJoin() how you had an instance of Player "player" and then cycled through the keySet to find the same Player and called it "registered".

```
Main.debug("Before For-Loop.");

    for (Player registered : activeMenus.keySet())
    {
        if (registered.equals(player))
        {
            Main.debug("Player Validation Passed -> " + registered.getName());

            ArrayList<Menu> playerMenus = activeMenus.get(registered);
```

I tried looking into Player.equals(Player) and seemed to be buggy for some people. Instead of storing and comparing instances of Players, I would:

- replace all uses of Player in HashMaps/Arrays to UUIDs (recommended anyway because storing Player can cause memory leaks). One can get the UUID with `Player.getUniqueId();`
- compare the UUIDs of the two Player objects, which could look something like
  `if (registered.getUniqueId() == player.getUniqueId())`.

In your case however, couldn't the comparison be completely avoided by replacing all instances of "registered" to "player"?

```
Main.debug("Before For-Loop.");

//  for (Player registered : activeMenus.keySet())
//  {
//      if (registered.equals(player))
//      {
            Main.debug("Player Validation Passed -> " + player.getName());

            ArrayList<Menu> playerMenus = activeMenus.get(player);
```

Sources:

- (Mar2014) http://bukkit.org/threads/psa-the-switch-to-uuids-potential-plugin-server-breakage.250915/
- (Sep2013) http://bukkit.org/threads/how-to-compare-players.171967/
- (Aug2011) http://bukkit.org/threads/solved-player-equals-differentplayer.33920/